# Ajax.BeginForm replaces whole page with partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having problems using `Ajax.BeginForm()` in my simple ASP.NET MVC application. I've searched SO for solution but nothing I found seems to help.

I've created a new project using the default Visual Studio 2015 template. I've changed the `Index.cshtml` file to:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
    <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div id="ajax-test"></div>

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Test", new AjaxOptions()
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "ajax-test",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    }))
    {
        <input type="submit" />
    }
</div>
```

I've added a new action to `HomeController`:

```
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return PartialView("Test");
    }
```

A new view `Home\Test.cshtml`:

```
Hello world
```

And, crucially, I've added a reference to the required JavaScript files to `_Layout.cshtml` (moving them to the top of the page doesn't help).

```
    ...
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I've verified the `jqueryval` bundle renders in the debug mode as:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

These entries were already present in `web.config` file:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

I would expect that when I press Submit, the div will be populated with 'Hello world'. Instead, the whole page is replaced with 'Hello world' and the browser is redirected to `/Home/Test`. No errors reported in developer tools.

What element of the puzzle is missing? I know similar questions have been asked on StackOverflow before but the usual answer was to include these JavaScript files, which I did. Above are all the changes I've done to the template project so I can't see what I could break.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've struggled with it for hours and managed to find the solution 5min after posting on StackOverflow. Typical.

I had to install a NuGet package `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobrusive.Ajax`, which is not installed by default, and add a reference to `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` to the page. I thought it has been merged in into `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` or something but no.

Comment: No!  why was this my problem too :( 4 hours.  Thank you very much for updating your OP with your answer!